# Can I use the Remote Platform option in Netbeans from Windows 10?

Tags: ssh, netbeans, pi, netbeans-12

I am trying to use my computer with windows 10 installed so that I can build and compile jar files but test them remotely on my raspberry pi4 down the hall.  This method worked fine when I was using a linux (Ubuntu) laptop, but unfortunately...the laptop broke, and now I'm installing linux on another computer...and in the meantime, I would like to continue working.  I have Apache Netbeans 12.3, java version 16, and here are the specifics of what is happening:  I can go into manage platforms, I can set up a remote platform, and can test it...and the connection tests out successfully.  However, when I go to File->ProjectProperties and select Categories->Run, in the drop-down box where you can usually select the platforms you have established....there are no options--it just offers Project Platform.  Maybe it's a windows thing?  A priviledge thing?  I can't find the answer...thanks in advance.

[This is the screen where the problem exists.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdwUb.png) The arrow points towards the drop down menu that won't drop down and acts like no other Platform has been defined.

Comment: [1] It's not necessarily related to your problem, but note that NetBeans 12.3 doesn't support Java 16. The most recent release you can use is Java 15, so can you try running NetBeans with JDK 15 as your default platform to verify that the problem still occurs? [2] What versions of NetBeans and Java were you using on Linux when everything worked? [3] Updating your question with a screen shot of the problem would be very helpful for those trying to replicate your problem.

Comment: I was using Java 11, I believe.  That system is no longer in operation now.  I think I will going to Java 15, as I notice that my programs will not run on the PI because of a linkage error the compiler says is due to me using a version of java that is too recent....but that might be something to do with using openjdk as opposed to the regular java runtime.  I'll post a pic here in a bit

Comment: OK. I doubt that the issue is anything to do with OpenJDK; it's much more likely that it's because you are using 16. Update your question if the problem persists when using 15 as your default platform. Also be sure to rebuild any applications that were built with JDK 16, using JDK 15 instead.

Comment: I just downgraded the runtime environment to JDK 11, and the problem has been solved.  Thank you.

Comment: Great. Could you please post an answer to your question, explaining the solution? Having the resolution detailed in an answer is much more helpful to the community than having it buried in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

By downgrading the JDK to JDK11, I was able to select newly existing Remote Platforms in Netbeans in the File->ProjectProperties window, under the Run category, as detailed in the picture above.